# Threads seem to be slowing down image processing C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am writing a function to change the values of the pixels in an image.  The way it works is by splitting up the task of shading each pixel into multiple threads.  For example if there are 4 threads then each one will shade every 4 pixels.  What I find strange is that the threaded approach is about a 1/10 of a second slower than doing it in a single loop. I can't figure out why this is since I have a quad core CPU and there is no real synchronization involved between the threads.  I would expect it to be about 4x faster minus a bit of overhead.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Note that I set nthreads=1 to measure the single loop approach.

FYI raster is a pointer in the class which points to a dynamic array of pixels.

```
void RGBImage::shade(Shader sh, size_t sx, size_t sy, size_t ex, size_t ey)
{
    validate();
    if(ex == 0)
        ex = width;
    if(ey == 0)
        ey = height;

    if(sx < 0 || sx >= width || sx >= ex || ex > width || sy < 0 || sy >= height || sy >= ey
            || ey > height)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Bounds Invalid");

    size_t w = ex - sx;
    size_t h = ey - sy;
    size_t nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    if(nthreads > MAX_THREADS)
        nthreads = MAX_THREADS;
    else if(nthreads < 1)
        nthreads = 1;

    size_t load_per_thread = w * h / nthreads;
    if(load_per_thread < MIN_THREAD_LOAD)
        nthreads = (w * h) / MIN_THREAD_LOAD;

    clock_t start = clock();
    if(nthreads > 1)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<std::thread[]> threads(new std::thread[nthreads]);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
            threads[i] = std::thread([=]()
            {   
                for(size_t p = i; p < (w * h); p += nthreads)
                {   
                    size_t x = sx + p % w;
                    size_t y = sy + p / w;
                    sh(raster[y * width + x], x, y);
                }
            });
        for(size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
            threads[i].join();
    }
    else
    {
        for(size_t p = 0; p < (w * h); ++p)
        {
            size_t x = sx + p % w;
            size_t y = sy + p / w;
            sh(raster[y * width + x], x, y);
        }
    }
    std::cout << ((float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << std::endl;
}
```

I took some of the advice ans changed up my function.

```
void RGBImage::shade(Shader sh, bool threads)
{
    validate();
    clock_t c = clock();
    if(threads)
    {
        int nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        size_t pix = width * height;
        if(nthreads < 1)
            nthreads = 1;
        else if(nthreads > MAX_THREADS)
            nthreads = MAX_THREADS;
        if(pix / nthreads < MIN_THREAD_LOAD)
            nthreads = pix / MIN_THREAD_LOAD;

        size_t pix_per_threads = pix / nthreads;

        std::unique_ptr<std::thread[]> t(new std::thread[nthreads]);
        for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
        {
            t[i] = std::thread([=]()
            {
                size_t offset = i * pix_per_threads;
                size_t x = offset % width;
                size_t y = offset / width;
                sh(raster + offset, *this, x, y, 
                        i == nthreads - 1 ? pix_per_threads + (width * height) % nthreads : pix_per_threads);
            });
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
            t[i].join();
    }
    else
    {
        sh(raster, *this, 0, 0, width * height);
    }
    std::cout << ((float)(clock() - c) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << std::endl;
}
```

Now it runs about 10x faster but the threaded version is still slower.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing  maybe?

Comment: Uh, I'm uncertain, but is each thread ending up with it's own copy of `raster`?  That could be impressive overhead maybe.  What is `raster`? And what is `sh`?

Comment: Why are you using `unique_ptr<std::thread[]>` instead of `vector<std::thread>`?

Comment: Perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA is worth a look

Comment: You should also look into OpenMP. OMP is a great way to quickly and easily implement multithreading for something like this. It also leaves your code looking a lot like it did originally, therefore it is easier to change if you are still developing the code/algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have done is maximized contention between threads.

You want to minimize it.

Threads should work on a scanline at a time (or more).  Divide your image into n blocks of roughly equal number of scanlines (left of image to right), and tell each thread to work on the nth block of scanlines.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.reserve(nthreads);
for(size_t i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
  size_t v_start = (h*i)/nthreads;
  size_t v_end = (h*(i+1))/nthreads;
  threads.push_back(std::thread([=]()
  {   
    for(size_t y = v_start; y < v_end; ++y)
    {   
      for (size_t x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
        sh(raster[y * width + x], x, y);
      }
    }
  }));
}
for(auto&& thread:threads)
  thread.join();
```

another approach is to grab the ppl (parallel patterns library) and use it.  It will dynamically balance the number of threads based on the current load and hardware specs, and might use thread pooling to reduce thread startup costs.

A serious concern is your `Shader sh`.  You do not want to be calling anything as expensive as a function pointer (or even more expensive, a `std::function`) on a per-pixel basis.

My general rule is that I write a "for each pixel" function that takes the pixel operation as a `F&&`, and pass it to a "for each scanline" function after wrapping the pixel-shader in an (in-header-file) scanline based operation.  The cost of indirection is then reduced to once per scanline.  In addition, the compiler may be able to optimize between pixel operations (say, doing SIMD), while a per-pixel call cannot be optimized this way.

A final problem with your "interleave" solution is it makes it impossible for the compiler to vectorize your code.  Vectorization can easily give a 3-4x speedup.

Comment: So it is the false sharing of `raster` then?

Comment: @MooingDuck it could be.  It could also be that the problem is completely memory bound, and the threading just wastes time starting up threads and cleaning them up.

Comment: Actually, yeah. Memory bound makes a lot more sense then any theory I came up with.  That would mean your answer isn't right though.

Comment: Ok this is good to know.  I was trying to write something generic.  Shader is an instance of std::function which I guess is bad.  Also I see how with small calculations the memory will be a limiting factor. Right now the Shader I was testing with just changes all the green pixels to full value.  Maybe if I did something more heavy like a convolution it would make a difference.

Comment: @MooingDuck I doubt it is memory bound: while there is a 100ms latency on a cache miss, access is pretty coherent and predictable after that.  The cache should "get ahead" of the code.  It is a possibility, but I doubt it.  Vectorization, contention and thread overhead seem more likely.

Comment: But even if the way I am doing it is not the fastest then shouldn't the threaded method be faster than the unthreaded way in the else?

Comment: @chasep255 A special note on this is to make sure to pay attention to how he changed your single for loop into a nested for loop. While a nested for loop feels wrong, doing an extra divide and/or mod each loop iteration will hurt as those are incredibly expensive operations. Not to mention that this syntax will make it easier to understand how you are accessing data from the raster array and will make software prefetching more efficient.

Comment: @chasep255 yep.  Write `template<class F> std::function< void(byte* data,size_t len, size_t x, size_t y) > make_scanline_op( F&& )` that takes a per-pixel op, and executes it on a line of pixels.  Write a `scanline_shade` in your .cpp file, and `template<class F> void shade` in the header file simply calls `scanline_sharder( make_scanline_op(std::forward<F>(f)), blah... )`.

Comment: Thats what I think I will do.  If I have 4 thread break the image into 4 rectangles.

Comment: @chasep255 yes, but give each thread as contiguous of memory as possible -- hence vertical split.  That is what I did above.  (if your image is tiled, you either multi-thread over each tile scanline (ok), or you give each thread an equal number of tiles (maybe better))

Comment: It is one continuous chunk of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well that answer is pretty simple.  The threaded solution was infact faster.  It was just consuming more clock() time and the clock() function is not good for timing threads.

Answer (score -2):

in C++ you can take advantage of those cores using parallelism or use amp (accelerated massive parallelism).  My vote will be to do the latter.

sample amp project: http://austin.codeplex.com/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/08/30/learn-c-amp.aspx

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the question is

Comment: The *standard* C++ language provides no support for using parallelism or amp.  Compiler specific `pragma`s need to be used.   You can take advantage of multiple cores in other languages.  Not sure what you are trying to communicate.